# __autoload($class) not working? class not found error

Tags: php, class, object, autoload

I am following some examples in the `PRO PHP AND JQUERY` book, but for some reason the examples doesn't work. Even the examples that I downloaded from the books site doesn't work. Not sure whats wrong, because I have done exactly as in the book..

/public/Index.php

```
include_once '../sys/core/init.inc.php';
$cal = new Calendar($dbo, "2010-01-01 12:00:00"); //ERROR Class 'Calendar' not found
```

/sys/core/init.inc.php

```
    function __autoload($class)
    {
        $filename = "../sys/class/class." . $class . ".inc.php";
        if ( file_exists($filename) )
        {
            include_once $filename;
        }
    }
```

/sys/class/class.calendar.inc.php

```
class Calendar extends DB_Connect
{
    private $_useDate;
    private $_m;
    private $_y;
    private $_daysInMonth;
    private $_startDay;

    /**
     * Create a database containg relevant info
     *
     * @param object $dbo a database object
     * @param string $useDate the date to build calender
     */

    public function __construct($dbo=NULL, $useDate=NULL)
    {
        /*
         * Call the parent constructor to check db object 
         */
        parent::__construct($dbo); 
    }


}
```

This is very annoying since every chapter in the books builds on this simple foundation. My guess is that `__autoload()` is the problem, but I have no idea..

Comment: alex is correct, but I'd also consider using [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) so multiple autoload functions can exist, if not by you, by external libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filepaths do not point to the right spots.

A better idea would be something like this in `Index.php`...

```
define('DOCROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

...and then modify your `__autoload()` like so...

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    $filename = DOCROOT . "/sys/class/class." . strtolower($class) . ".inc.php";
    if ( file_exists($filename) )
    {
        include_once $filename;
    }
}
```

You should `strotlower()` the filename before including it, as your class is `Calendar` but your filename has `calendar`.

Comment: Filenames on Windows are case insensitive, in most UNIX flavors are case sensitive. Perhaps the code is for Windows.

Comment: @AbiusX Why would you tie your code to a platform needlessly, especially PHP?

Comment: I wont but the writer of the tutorial might have! I never use Windows.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are discouraged from using __autoload() in new code as it MAY BE DEPRECATED OR REMOVED IN THE FUTURE, according to official doc; instead, use spl_autoload_register() like so:

```
//first define a custom function
function myAutoLoader( $className ){

    $path = strtolower( path/to/your/class/ . $className . '.php' );

    include_once( $path );

}
```

Notice how we strtolower() the $className. This to make sure that the class name ( usually starts with upper case ) tallies with the filename ( usually all in lower case ). In some environment ( especially Windows ), this may not be necessary, but just to be on a safer side. For example, I do not have to in my development environment which is Windows but my production environment( debian ) will not take it.

Then pass that function name as argument into spl_autoload_regsiter. Note that the function name is string

```
 //Now use spl_autoload_register()
spl_autoload_register( 'myAutoLoader' );
```

If you wish to catch exception, you may do something like this in your custom function like so:

```
//first define a custom function with exception handling
function myAutoLoader( $className ){

    $path = strtolower( path/to/your/class/ . $className . '.php' );

    include_once( $path );

    if( !class_exists( $className, false ) ){
       throw new RuntimeException( 'Class '. $className . ' has not been         
       loaded yet' ); 
    }
}

//then the spl_autoload_register(), just like before
spl_autoload_register( 'myAutoLoader' );
```

You will then have to catch the thrown exception when declaring your class.

Comment: There is no mention of deprecation on the official documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php

Comment: @BenO Are you sure? Let me quote from the same link you cited: "Warning This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged."

Comment: You are correct, this may have been recently changed. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I got this type error by use `'` replaced `"`,if use `"`, there is no this error:

The right writing:

```
function __autoload($class) {

    echo HOME_INC."/$class.class.php";

    if(is_file(HOME_INC."/$class.class.php")){

        include_once HOME_INC."/$class.class.php";
    }elseif(is_file(ADMIN_INC."/$class.class.php")){

        include_once ADMIN_INC."/$class.class.php";
    }
}
```

The wrong writing:

```
function __autoload($class) {

    echo HOME_INC.'/$class.class.php';

    if(is_file(HOME_INC.'/$class.class.php')){

        include_once HOME_INC.'/$class.class.php';
    }elseif(is_file(ADMIN_INC.'/$class.class.php')){

        include_once ADMIN_INC.'/$class.class.php';
    }
}
```